# Can't install fastlane on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastlane, macos-catalina

As per the steps given in fastlane [docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/), I am not able to install fastlane.

After running `brew cask install fastlane`, I get this pop up:
[image]

If I try to run from gem with `sudo gem install fastlane`, I get this error:
[image]

What I see is the ruby.h file is missing from the directory. As it says in the error, I need to install the ruby-dev environment separately. But I could not find how to do that. I saw `apt-get` commands for this, but then what about the ruby installed via brew?

ruby -v: ruby 2.6.3p62
brew -v: Homebrew 2.1.10
brew upgrade ruby: ruby 2.6.3 already installed

Comment: Your link to the docs is `http://sudo%20gem%20install%20-n%20/usr/local/bin%20fastlane%20--verbose`

Comment: corrected the link

Answer (score 2):

Since the error says we have to instal ruby as a separate package for development, I had to install `rbenv` as shown on [ROR's](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave) website. You can check the full problem and solution [here](https://snippetsource.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/fastlane-installation-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby/).

Comment: `sudo gem install fastlane -NV` – this is how you can break your system!

Comment: please do thing that way: `gem install  --user-install fastlane -NV` - as this way you will avoid writing shared gems, avoid granting any gem to access system with a root privilege.

Comment: @OlegShanyuk seems to have worked with sudo. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyF ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ well, it should work with sudo indeed, just saying: mastering to use gems without sudo is a nice skill, and safe way for your system

Answer (score 0):

Run this to disable Gatekeeper:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Then install and run fastlane. When done, run this to re-enable Gatekeeper:

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

It will remember that you have permitted the application after re-enabling Gatekeeper and you will not have to run these commands every time you use it.

Comment: Please don't! It's too much for a scripting tool. Problem is in the dependency graph. And now it's becoming way more obvious – security is a thing for developers too.

Comment: This permits the executable that otherwise cannot be run on Catalina. It is immediately re-enabled. There's absolutely no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15183 
This is a common issue which nobody can solve it.

Comment: See my answer. I am running Catalina beta and fastlane successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't update fastlane version
try

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin fastlane`